# CSS vertical align different text size

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

Assuming the following HTML:

```
​<p><span style="font-size: 40px;">A</span>a​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​</p>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Is it possible to get the second character to align to the center of the first?

### Actual Result

The second character is aligned to the **bottom** of the first character in [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/uEu6B/):

[image]

### Expected Result

However, I want the second character to be aligned to the **middle** of the first character:

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just add in the `vertical-align:middle;` style.

http://jsfiddle.net/uEu6B/1/

Answer (score 5):

Add [`vertical-align:middle;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/vertical-align) to the `<span>` ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/AgBhW/)):

```html
<p><span style="font-size: 40px;vertical-align: middle;">A</span>a</p>​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Comment: the question was changed after I answered it.